# Hibernate Queries logging should be avoided?

Tags: hibernate, logging, jboss5.x, jboss-tools

I am using JPA for my project ...

My question is : `Whenever we are executing some query using the JPA the query is logged in the server.log file of the **JBOSS** .` Am using Jboss log4J.

But i want to avoid printing the query in the server.log file .
without changing the below property:

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
```

Instead i tried :

```
<category name="org.hibernate">
        <priority value="ERROR" />
    </category>
```

in `log4j.xml`  , eventhough queries are logging in the console or server.log for successfull query .

Can anyone please help me on this how to achieve this ... ?

Where i have to change the Configuration to avoid the query logging in the server.log ?

Comment: Is quite a weird requirement, are you logging them to another file? otherwise why burden the application with the overhead?

Comment: @ssedano yes based on criteria we are logging into different logs ...

Comment: ok, paste the relevant part of the log4j.xml please

Comment: @ssedano , i have already pasted the code related to hibernate in log4j.xml ... the above snippet is the  only code am using in log4j.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might struggle to do this.

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
```

Is really a development setting which writes the generated SQL to stdout not to your logger.

Take a look at `org.hibernate.jdbc.util.SQLStatementLogger` to confirm.

The logging of the SQL to your configured logging mechanism is an entirely different thing and is written to `org.hibernate.SQL`.

Therefore to avoid writing SQL anywhere you will need to set:

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
```

and use the following log setting:

```
<category name="org.hibernate">
  <priority value="INFO" />
</category>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer ... if am not wrong , if we use value="INFO" then also log will be printed ... what i want is i dont want the queries to be printed in the log ... i tried the above also but failed :(

Comment: yeah i have set ... 
but still am able to see the queries logging in console